# Istio Routing - How to route default traffic to a specific service from istio gateway

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I am trying to implement following routing strategy in my K8S cluster.

1. route `foo/bar/*` requests to `bar-service`
2. route `foo/*` requests (except `foo/bar/*`) requests to `foo-service`

I am new to istio and this strategy was already implemented with nginx ingress controller using regex but could not find a way in istio gateway and virtual service.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a VirtualService and HTTP route rules. Let's say you have App1:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app1
          image: ghcr.io/trstringer/httpbin2:0.1.0
          command: ["/httpbin2"]
          args:
            - "--message-hostname"
            - "--port"
            - "8080"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

And a second app, App2:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app2
          image: ghcr.io/trstringer/httpbin2:0.1.0
          command: ["/httpbin2"]
          args:
            - "--message-hostname"
            - "--port"
            - "8080"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app2
spec:
  selector:
    app: app2
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

In the event that you want `app2` to serve all requests to `/specific-route`, and all other requests to `app1`, you'd first have to create a `Gateway`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: app-routing
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "httpbin2.com"
```

Now wire up a `VirtualService` to this `Gateway`, which will handle the routing:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: appvs
spec:
  hosts:
    - "httpbin2.com"
  gateways:
    - app-routing
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /specific-route
      route:
        - destination:
            host: app2
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: app1
```

If you look at `VirtualService.spec.http` you'll find the list of [`HTTPRoute`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute)s.

Here is where you define the ordered list of routes. The first one that is matched will be used, so you have to make sure the sub route is listed first.

Now if you do the following:

```
$ curl -H "host: httpbin2.com" http://20.102.18.97/specific-route/more
(app2-75548c4dd9-cjdzd)
```

You'll see the request goes to app2. But if you do a different route that doesn't match that, it'll fall back to app1:

```
curl -H "host: httpbin2.com" http://20.102.18.97/more/things/here
(app1-549c548585-8cqld)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with edit the virtulaservice

- name: "/foo/bar/"
  match:

  - uri:
    prefix: /foo/bar/*
    rewrite:
    uri: /
    route:
  - destination:
    host: bar-service
    port:
    number: 80
- name: "foo/*"
  match:

  - uri:
    prefix: /foo/*
    rewrite:
    uri: /
    route:
  - destination:
    host: foo-service
    port:
    number: 80

Comment: Above configuration in istio virtual service will give following error.  Warning: virtualService rule #1 match #0 of prefix /foo/bar/* is not used (duplicate/overlapping match in rule #0 of prefix /foo on #0)

Comment: didn't work. always routing to `bar-service`.

Answer (score 0):

Below virtual service can route requests to different foo, bar service respectively.  if further change is required on request path change the regex pattern accordingly

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: fooapplication
  namespace: default
spec:
  gateways:
  - foo-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /foo
     route:
    - destination:
        host: foo-service
        port:
          number: 8080
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: /foo.*
    rewrite:
      uri: /bar-service
    route:
    - destination:
        host: bar-service
        port:
          number: 8080
```